# HashSet allows duplicates

Tags: java, duplicates, hashset

I can't seem to get a `HashSet` instance to work as expected. The code I used is as follows:

```
import testing.Subclass;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class tester {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HashSet<Subclass> set = new HashSet<Subclass>();
    set.add(new Subclass("007812"));
    set.add(new Subclass("007813"));
    System.out.println("Set size " + set.size());
    set.add(new Subclass("007812"));
    System.out.println("Set size " + set.size());

    for(Subclass sub : set) {
      System.out.println(" sub acctNbr " + sub.getAcctNbr());
    }
  }
}
```

Subclass

```
public class Subclass implements Comparable<Subclass> {

  public Subclass(String acctNbr) {
    this.acctNbr = acctNbr;
  }
  private String acctNbr;
  public String getAcctNbr() {
    return this.acctNbr;
  }
  public int compareTo(Subclass other) {
    return this.getAcctNbr().compareTo(other.getAcctNbr());
  }

  public boolean equals(Subclass other) {
    if(other.getAcctNbr().equals(this.getAcctNbr()))
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
  public int hashCode() {
    return acctNbr.hashCode();
  }
}
```

This code outputs

```
sross@sross-workstation:~/Documents$ javac testing/Subclass.java
sross@sross-workstation:~/Documents$ javac tester.java
sross@sross-workstation:~/Documents$ java tester
Set size 2
Set size 3
 sub acctNbr 007812
 sub acctNbr 007812
 sub acctNbr 007813
sross@sross-workstation:~/Documents$
```

Comment: What behavior do you expect, and how is it different from the behavior you're seeing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to override `equals(Object)`.  Instead of doing this you've implemented an `equals` method with signature `equals(Subclass)`.  Consequently your `HashSet` is using the default `equals(Object)` method defined on `Object` for equality testing.

The default `equals(Object)` implementation is based on object identity, and hence the set "allows" you to add two `String`s that, whilst semantically equal, are not the same object.

Comment: Don't forget to override hashCode() as well.

Comment: The OP had already overridden hashCode() correctly, but this is still an important point.

Answer (score 6):

You did not correctly override `Object.equals()`.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if ((other == null) || !(other instanceof Subclass)) {
        return false;
    }
    return ((Sublcass) other).getAcctNbr().equals(this.getAcctNbr());
}
```

The method `boolean equals(Subclass other)` creates a second method which is not what you intended to do.

Comment: Boo to only an optional override tag.

Comment: You don't need to check for null, since `instanceof` returns false for a null reference.

Comment: Agreed, strict checking of @Override would have pointed out the problem immediately.

Comment: You can optimise this by first checking if this == other.  Also, you need to cast 'other' before you can call getAcctNbr() on it.

public boolean equals(Object o) { return this == o || (o instanceof Subclass && acctNbr.equals(((Subclass)o).getAcctNbr)); }

Answer (score 3):

Two meta-points:

First, get in the habit of using `@Override` every time you believe you are overriding a method. That would have caused your example code to fail to compile, leading you to discover the problem.

Second, if you're using an IDE, and it didn't highlight a nice bold warning for you, it is misconfigured!  You should fix it!

And if you're not using an IDE -- you really, really should be.  As soon as you typed `public boolean equals(Subclass other)`, the text would change color and a warning would be displayed telling you what your likely problem is.

Incidentally, the standard idiom for `equals()` that I've converged on is this:

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object object) {
  if (object instanceof Subclass) {
    Subclass that = (Subclass) object;
    return this.anInt == that.anInt
        && this.aString.equals(that.aString); // for example
  }
  return false;
}
```

In *some* cases, it is worth prepending an `if (object == this) { return true; }` but it's really not worthwhile to make a regular habit of it.

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the same problem, as everyone said you need to override the right `public boolean equals(Object o)` method. But that's not enough!

It is also necessary to override `public int hashCode()` (as you did), otherwise, java wouldn't call the `equals` method at all.

Answer (score 0):

First guess, it looks like your `equals(Subclass other)` ought to be `equals(Object other)` in order to override the `java.lang.Object.equals()` method, as you want.  Probably the set is calling the underlying `equals()` implementation.

Comment: Yeah, or more precisely, exactly what Bombe said.

Answer (score 0):

Your equals method is never called. The signature of `equals` requires that it take an `Object`, not some other class (including whatever class happens to be implementing `equals`).

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    ...
}
```