# HashSet allowed addition of duplicate element

Tags: java, hashset

While stumbling around i found this very interesting program which allows addition of duplicate elements to `HashSet`. I hope someone can explain it nicely

```
public class Human implements Comparable<Human> {
    Integer age;
    public Human(int age) {
    this.age = age;
    }
    public int compareTo(Human h) {
    return h.age.compareTo(this.age);
    }
    public String toString() {
    return ""+this.age;
    }

}
```

Main class

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Human> humans = new HashSet<Human>();
        humans.add(new Human(13));
        humans.add(new Human(33));
        humans.add(new Human(21));
        humans.add(new Human(21));
        System.out.println("Size : "+humans.size());
        System.out.print(humans);
    }

    }
```

Expected Output : `[21, 33, 13]`

Instead got this : `[21, 21, 33, 13]`

Comment: Hash hash hash hash. Hash hash hash. Hash hash. Hash.

Comment: The `toString()` implementation in the program should had been `this.age.toString()`. Using `""+` concatenation is suboptimal here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing something HashSet duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663506/missing-something-hashset-duplicates)

Comment: @Unihedron strictly speaking, it all depends on the manner in which toString() will be called - if it's for debugging or single calls only, return ""+age; would be OK in my book, as it's both quickly written and easy to modify, so changing it would be premature op IMO. If it's actually used somewhere serious, especially in a loop - I'd go with simple age.toString(); (this. is not needed in this case, as the name age is unambiguous).

Answer (score 7):

Your class doesn't implement `#hashCode` nor `#equals` - failing the implementation contract of HashMap (and HashSet too, since it's backed by HashMap internally).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Since your elements use `Object.hashCode()`/`equals()`, the value of the fields of the object aren't taken into account, the only thing that actually matters is the memory address of the object [since it's the only thing differentiating objects without explicit `hashCode()`/`equals()`].

Defining a comparator *doesn't* help when using a hash-based solution - it's only enough for *sorted collections*.

As a side note: this is actually **good** in case of your code - do you expect two Human with the same age to be one person? It's the reason for using HashXXX in this case that is unclear for me - it gives no benefit over a e.g. ArrayList in this particular case...

Edit: if you're completely sure you want that strange behaviour - simply provide

```
public int hashCode() {
    return age;
}

public boolean equals( Object obj ) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if ( !(obj instanceof Human) ) // null check included for free ^_~
      return false;
    return age == ((Human)obj).age;
}
```

Comment: To my understanding such sorted collections include `TreeSet`s?

Comment: @Unihedron yup. TreeSet requires Comparator (either implemented or passed explicitly), otherwise it uses natural ordering of the elements.